# How to find my cookie's resource and come from?

Tags: http, session, cookies, samesite

There is a cookie that named by TS0157d632 and I want to assign SameSite attribute for it. But I did not find that cookie comes from? I think, SSL certificates affect it because same code published another site which is not certificated on same domain and the cookie did not occur.

Cookie name TS0157d632 and the web site is https://www.sekerleasing.com.tr/

Comment: You need to include more context for a meaningful answer to this question. Is `sekerleasing.com` your site? If you do not own the site, you cannot affect the cookies for it.

If it is your site, what is it running on? What language, framework, etc. That will determine how the `SameSite` attribute is set.

Comment: @rowan_m We developed, using .NET Framework 4.7.2 version on IIS server upper 7.0 and than C# language. As I mentioned above, SSL certificates can affect because of there is the same code that published another site which is not certificated on same domain and the cookie did not occur..